# Life Counter Keeps Resetting

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have recently gotten into pygame and I am having trouble. My life counter is not working in my program.

```
import pygame, time, random

pygame.init() # Initializes Pygame

display_width = 1280
display_height = 720

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Cube Game')

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def life(lives):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25);
    text = font.render("Lives: " + str(lives), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(1200,5))

def score(count):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25);
    text = font.render("Score: " + str(count), True, white)
    gameDisplay.blit(text,(5,5))

def enemyBall(ballx, bally, ballr, color):
    pygame.draw.circle(gameDisplay, color, [ballx, bally], ballr)

# Creates Location for the Cube
def cube(x,y,side):
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, white, [x, y, side, side])

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, white)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def message_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 50)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    time.sleep(2)

    __init__()

def dead():
    gameDisplay.fill(black)
    message_display('You have fallen out of the castle and died!')


# Game Loop
def __init__():
    x = ((display_width/2) - 30)
    y = (display_height - 70)
    side = 60

    x_change = 0

    ballx_change = 25
    bally_change = 25
    ball_radius = 50

    ball_startx = random.randrange(26, (display_width-ball_radius-1))
    ball_starty = random.randrange((ball_radius+1), 100)

    death = False
    goodbye = False
    myLives = 3
    myScore = 0


    # If Player has not Died
    while not death:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                death = True
                pygame.display.quit()
                pygame.quit()
                quit()


            # Key is still Pressed
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    x_change = -10
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 10

            # Key is no longer Pressed
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 0

        x += x_change


        gameDisplay.fill(black)

        # Defines the enemy ball
        enemyBall(ball_startx, ball_starty, ball_radius, white)
        ball_startx += ballx_change
        ball_starty += bally_change

        # Wall Collision
        if ball_startx - ball_radius <= 0 or ball_startx + ball_radius >= display_width:
            ballx_change = -ballx_change
            myScore += 1
        if ball_starty - ball_radius <= 0 or ball_starty + ball_radius >= display_height:
            bally_change = -bally_change
            myScore += 1

        # Determines Player Position
        cube(x,y,side)

        # Score and Life Counter
        score(myScore)
        life(myLives)

        # Death by Abyss
        if x > display_width or x < -50:
            myLives -= 1
            dead()

        # Death by Ball
        if ball_startx + ball_radius >= x and ball_startx - ball_radius <= x + side:
            if ball_starty + ball_radius >= y and ball_starty - ball_radius <= y + side:
                myLives -= 1
                dead()

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

time.sleep(2)
__init__()
pygame.display.quit()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I have a statement that decreases the life counter by one when the player dies. However, the life counter seems to reset to 3 (the original amount). What do I have to change to fix the life counter? Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service. Please reduce code to minimal reproducible example and perhaps you'll find your bug along the way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dead() calls message_display() which calls your **init**() again. On every **init**() call, you set myLives = 3 again.

Answer (score 0):

When the player dies, you call `dead()`.

`dead()` calls `message_display()`.

`message_display()` calls `__init__()` again (even though it was already running).

The beginning of `__init__()` says `myLives = 3`.

If you don't want the variable reset to 3 when the player dies, don't keep calling `__init__` again, because the start of that function always resets `myLives` to 3.